# How to set lineeditor to vi-mode in JShell

Tags: vi, jshell, jline, inline-editor

How to set lineeditor to **vi-mode** in JShell?

The setting `set editing-mode vi` is in both `$HOME/.inputrc` and `$HOME/.jline.rc`, but it seems like `Jshell` does not respect any of them.

Comment: @romainl As I mentioned above, it seems like Jshell doesn't respect `.jline.rc`. I know Jshell uses JLine2, but I didn't find why in that [issue tracker](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues)

Comment: Hint: that issue tracker is *not* read-only.